# Every time I touch an object a full-render starts

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, customization

I don't know what setting I switched, or what happened, but for some reason now every time I move, scale or rotate an object in the 3d View - blender starts a render. I am not talking about the 3d View being in "Rendered" mode. I am talking about the same behavior as when you click the "Render" button (switch to image editor, begin full render). This is driving me crazy and I can't seem to figure out how to turn it off or what I did to start it. It happens whether I use the mouse or keys. If I open a new document the behavior goes away so it is probably a preference setting(?) If you can help, I will be eternally grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the compositor windows turn off Auto Render

[image]

Comment: Good Lord - I did not see it, obviously. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hit <kbd>Z</kbd> twice.

This switches you out of *Render Preview* mode, into *Wireframe*, then back to *Solid* mode.

Comment: "I am not talking about the 3d View being in "Rendered" mode."

Comment: @Jerryno Good catch, I missed that. Cegaton's answer looks like the right one.