# When I connect nodes the image starts blinking

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to composite a still image, but every time I click on "Use Nodes", the image node starts acting weird/blinking. Then at the top of the toolbar it says it's trying to cancel something with the percentages fluctuating from 0 to 100 [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M5HT.jpg). My render result ends up going straight white or gray.

Prior to this I was rendering an animation straight to mp4 format just so I can quickly preview it. Instead of compositing an entire image sequence I want to composite one still of it, but the nodes start having issues. This isn't the first time this has occurred.

Comment: Are you doing this while rendering?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46742/how-can-i-disable-auto-compositing

Comment: @VRM No, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was due to Animation Nodes making calculations in the background.  Once I severed some of the AN connections everything went back to normal.